# Can we *please* have an upload image button on the mobile site's post editor?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

Like the title says. It's super weird that there isn't one. Workaround is to switch to desktop site and upload from there, although this is really cumbersome given that making the switch mid post clears the post.

Comment: Hypothetically speaking... would preserving the post text be at least enough of an improvement? Just thinking in terms of "do we need to find a designer with enough free time to come up with a mobile upload dialog that works on a number of devices".

Comment: @AdamLear That would help the workaround and would be a big improvement. Still, the desktop site upload dialog already seems to work fine on Android devices. Does it not work on iOS?

Comment: @JasonC according to the dupe, it works fine in iOS too.

Comment: @AdamLear ^ Then yeah why not just add the button just like the desktop site and use the existing dialog?

Comment: Er, sure, it *works*, but it sucks in terms of UX. Doesn't even fit on my screen on an iPhone 6. If we're gonna support the feature in the mobile web UI (and I agree that we should), simply using the desktop popup that doesn't scale correctly and isn't easy to use without zooming isn't the right/complete fix here.

Comment: @AdamLear It sucks less than toggling between desktop and mobile mode would (if post text were preserved). Maybe. I mean you're gonna be exposed to it anyways if you have to switch to desktop mode, might as well skip the middle man until somebody gets around to actually designing a reasonable dialog. But preserving post text would be fine. And it keeps the pro image up, I suppose -- nobody's going to be surprised about a crappy looking dialog if they're in desktop mode.

Comment: @JasonC Sort of, if you already know it's not officially supported for mobile. Otherwise it's pretty janky. IIRC (without code in front of me), at least preserving the post content is pretty easy. We should do that regardless of image needs. I'll ping folks tomorrow to see what it'd take to design an upload dialog for mobile in addition to that.